# Rank of a (3x5) matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

I got this matrix :

[image]

For me, since Column 1 = Column 3 = Column 4

It implies that the **maximum** rank of this matrix **should be 2.**
Since Column 2 is linearly independent of Column 5, the rank of this matrix **is equal to 2.**
This is coherent to the definition of the rank and to the fact that a (3x5) matrix has a rank inferior to 3.

**My question is : Is my reasoning false ?**

Comment: Since col1 = col3 = col4, we know that col3 and col4 are redundant when talking about the dimension of the column space... It might still be the case that col1,col2,col5 form a linearly independent set in which case the rank would still be $3$.  You seem to have discounted every copy of the redundant column when you should have still kept one copy of the redundant column.

Comment: Oh yeah that's right, got it !!

Comment: Of course... by the fact that there are only three rows, we knew from a completely different argument that the rank should be at most $3$...  Now, the question is whether the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}5&4&2\\5&5&4\\1&2&1\end{pmatrix}$ is invertible / full-rank.  If it is, then we have finished proving the rank of your original matrix is $3$.  If it is not, then your rank is less than $3$, but is clearly more than $1$ since clearly col1 is independent of col2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the rank of the matrix in this case is 3. Firstly the matrix is a short-wide matrix $(m<n)$. So maximum rank is m at the most

The rank depends on the number of pivot elements the matrix. I would say that your statement "Column 1 = Column 3 = Column 4" is wrong. You can say that Columns 1, 2 & 3 are Linearly Dependent Vectors. If you reduce the matrix by performing row operations you will end to at this state

$$
\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Now we can perform column operation and send either two from columns 1, 3 & 4 to $[0]$ but not all. Because one stays to be a Identity vector no matter what.

One more way to look at is Column Space of the matrix:

$$
C(Matrix) = c1 \begin{bmatrix} 5 \\5 \\4 \\ \end{bmatrix} + c2 \begin{bmatrix} 4 \\5 \\2 \end{bmatrix} + c3 \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\4 \\1 \\ \end{bmatrix}
$$

$$
rank(Matrix) = dim(C(Matrix))
$$

Therefore, rank is 3.

Comment: If this answers your question, please close this discussion

Answer (score 0):

Rank = 3

I removed the 3 linearly independent matrices where I should have removed only two.
It leads us to a 3x3 matrix with 3 linearly independant columns